# PHP extract string before character and after character

Tags: php

I am trying to come up with a validation class, but I need to grab options and put them into an array after '[' and before ']'. So for example:

```
$dropdown = 'required|valid_option[general,recruitment,activities]';
```

Then I have something like this:

```
if(strops($str, '[')) {
   // this string contains options so grab them before ] and after [
}
```

I need to grab the general,recruitment,activities and then I know how to split them using `explode()` and then put them into an array with `array_push` or something like that, but I really need to figure out how to grab that string after [ and before ] somehow. I can't figure it out. I'm guessing it uses a `preg_match` of some sort?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: you are right, sorry forgot to clarify that. I have `$rules` as an array containing (`required,valid_option[options here]`)... each of those are exploded on the `|` so `$rule` contains `'valid_option[option,option,option]'` - I'm trying to use `<` that string over there.

I think someone answered on how to grab the options, now how do I grab the 'valid_option' part? I'm guessing it's something like:

```
substr($rule, 0, $pos1)
```

Comment: What you should be looking into is a regex. That's the easiest option. Don't write five lines of explode workarounds.

Comment: [`preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', 'required|valid_option[general,recruitment,activities]', $matches); var_dump($matches);`](https://eval.in/40450)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
preg_match_all("~(.*)\[(.*?)\]~", $valid_options, $matches);
```

`$matches` will be an array of what the regexp matched.

And the array will look like:

```
array
  0 => string 'valid_option[general,test,test2,recruitment,activities]'
  1 => string 'valid_option'
  2 => string 'general,test,test2,recruitment,activities'
```

Comment: Wow your solution is very short. So does preg_match automatically create that new_str variable or do I have to initiate it first? And would you know how to grab the 'valid_option' part of the string before the '[' in a simple solution like you just did?

Comment: Yes, it will initialize it for you. For the second part of the question, i didn't understand precisely what part exactly do you want to grab? I made an edit since `$new_str` is actually an array.

Comment: Ah $new_str will be an array? How so? Will it just contain 0 => 'option1', 1 => 'option2', 2 => 'option3' ??
For the second part, $valid_options will contain this exact string 'valid_option[option1,option2,option3]' before anything happens to it. So your preg_match statement will grab 'option1,option2,option3' and put it into an array correct? I want to know how to grab 'valid_option'.. the actual rule name WITHOUT the options part '[option1,option2,option3]'.

Comment: Nevermind this is what preg_match returns : http://intellectproductions.com/test/test.php

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$pos1 = strpos($dropdown, '[');
$pos2 = strpos($dropdown, ']');
$options = substr($dropdown, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1);
```

As for the part before the square bracket that would be `substr($dropdown, 0, $pos1 - 1);` then explode on |

Edit: then explode $options on ',' and | as you mentioned in the first place.

Comment: OP should explode on `|` then use this code. Your code makes it seem like he should do it on the whole thing, which is why I'm thinking someone down voted you after I up voted you.

Comment: Wait I edited my question. I already extracted the rules.. required is one rule, valid_option[options here] is another rule. So say we have valid_option[......] in a variable called $rule.. how would we get the valid_option part? Before the [?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I edited my answer. However, OP clearly stated he knew how to operate an explode once the string contained between square brackets was found.

Comment: Peanut: `substr( $dropdown, 0, $strposOfFirstLeftBracket - 1 )`